# How to have a page link activated on wordpress navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I've created my own wordpress theme from HTML.
I want to have the page link activated once the user click on a page.

Home page is activated here but I'm browsing "our works" https://i.stack.imgur.com/yclnK.png

This is the code I used in header.php in theme:

`<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="<?php bloginfo('home'); ?>">HOME</a></li>
<?php wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order'); ?>`

How can I use my css "Current-menu-item" that my page link can be activated while a user viewing the page they clicked.

I appreciate your valuable comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can depend on the theme and the code you used but a quick way will be to use the body, that is if you are using something like this in your header:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

This will echo the current page class, something like this:

```
<body class="page page-id-125 page-parent page-template page-template-page-statistics page-template-page-statistics-php logged-in">
```

Then you can style it as follows:

```
.page-id-125 .current-menu-item{...}
```